# Merging plotly scatter plots into one figure

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, plotly

I want to create a single figure containing my 3 scatterplots. I'm stuck using plotly and i don't want to use subplots to display the 3 plots next to eachother. The plots have to be in the same figure showing the markers in 1 graph.

Comment: They wouldn't let me add code so it's in the answers...

Comment: You can probably get a better answer to your question if you provide a code sample to your question. It will help others see what you currently have with any potential problems and what the solution to your problem might be. You edit your question and paste part of your code in it.

Answer (score 0):

```
import plotly.express as px
import plotly.graph_objects as go 
from plotly.subplots import make_subplots

import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/idc9/stor390/master/data/movies.csv')
df.head(650)

#labelling
df["is_bad_review_audience"] = df["audience_score"].apply(lambda x: 1 if x < 50 else 0)
df["is_bad_review_critics"] = df["critics_score"].apply(lambda x: 1 if x < 50 else 0)
dfFig1 = df.loc[(df['genre']=='Drama')]

dfa = df.loc[(df['best_actor_win']=='yes')]
dfas = df.loc[(df['best_actress_win']=='yes')]
dfbp = df.loc[(df['best_pic_win']=='yes')]


dfFig2 = df.loc[(df['genre']=='Drama') | (df['genre'] == 'Horror')]
dfFig2['imdb_score'] = dfFig2['imdb_rating'] * 10
dfFig2
list(df)

figa=px.scatter(dfa
               ,x="audience_score"
               ,y="critics_score"
               ,color="best_actor_win"
               ,symbol="genre"
               ,height=400)

figa.update_layout(
    title="Plot Title",
    xaxis_title="x Axis Title",
    yaxis_title="y Axis Title",
    font=dict(
        family="Courier New, monospace",
        size=18,
        color="#7f7f7f"
    )
)
figa.show()
figas=px.scatter(dfas
               ,x="audience_score"
               ,y="critics_score"
               ,color="best_actress_win"
               ,symbol="genre"
               ,height=400)

figas.update_layout(
    title="Plot Title",
    xaxis_title="x Axis Title",
    yaxis_title="y Axis Title",
    font=dict(
        family="Courier New, monospace",
        size=18,
        color="#7f7f7f"
    )
)
figas.show()
figbp=px.scatter(dfas
               ,x="audience_score"
               ,y="critics_score"
               ,color="best_pic_win"
               ,symbol="genre"
               ,height=400)

figbp.update_layout(
    title="Plot Title",
    xaxis_title="x Axis Title",
    yaxis_title="y Axis Title",
    font=dict(
        family="Courier New, monospace",
        size=18,
        color="#7f7f7f"
    )
)
figbp.show()
```

Comment: As per your comment, does the code in this answer actaully belong in the question instead?